# If $|G|=3\cdot7$, $K\unlhd G$ with $|K|=3$. Then $K\leq Z(G)$ and $G$ is cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The hint was: consider automorphisms of $K$.

Clearly $K=\langle k|k^3=1\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_3}$, and so $|Aut(K)|=2$, one is the identity map, and the other sends $k$ to $k^2$.

But that is as far as I can get. Do I need to use Sylow theory to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \in G$. Then $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism. Thus

- $gkg^{-1} = k$ or
- $gkg^{-1} = k^2$

Also, since $G/K$ is cyclic of order $7$, $g^{-7}kg^7 = k$. Now apply the automorphism $x \mapsto gxg^{-1}$ seven times.

Comment: I established that $K$ lies in $Z(G)$. Since $G/K$ is cyclic, can I thus conclude that $G$ is cyclic?

Comment: @Sid If you've proven that theorem you can use it. It isn't so obvious that you can use it without comment.

Comment: Nah it doesn't work. $G/K$ cyclic does not imply $G$ is cyclic. I'm guessing I'll have to use the fact that $K\leq Z(G)$. By correspondence theorem $Z(G)/K \leq G/K$. So $Z(G)$ either has to be $K$ or $G$ by Lagrange theorem...

Comment: @Sid It is a standard exercise that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is Abelian. Using that idea, you can show that $G$ is Abelian of order $3 \cdot 7$ and hence is cyclic by the Structure Theorem for Finite Abelian Groups.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I get it.